# ASP.NET thread switching

Tags: asp.net, multithreading

I read somewhere (I can't remember where) that it is possible, in certain circumstances, for an ASP.NET response to be switched, while being processed, between threadpool threads - sometimes in the middle of an executing method.

Is this true? If so, how is this accomplished? If not, what could the author possibly have meant by this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the middle of an executing method? I've never heard of that... But in the middle of an executing page; yes:

This can happen when doing an asyncronous operation using either AddOnPreRenderCompleteAsync(...) or RegisterAsyncTask(...).

These methods will do an async call, and free the current thread while waiting for the response. After getting a response, the page instance will continue on an available thread.

Comment: Ah - this must be what the author meant. Thanks a bunch Arjan =)